# Constitutionally can the judge issue an arrest warrant for driving without a license?

Tags: united-states, driving

went to court and I asked for a appeal and  didn't have the money for the appeal so can they arrest  for this...??? Or make  payment to the fine which she try to make sign but didn't..

Comment: It is not clear what happened or what your question is. Who is "she"? The judge? The accused person? Also, what state is involved? This would be a matter of state law.

Comment: What exactly happened?  You were adjudicated guilty of driving without a license after a hearing?  You plead guilty?  "Make sign" refers to what?

Answer (score 4):

Driving without a license is illegal in every state in the US, and a judge presented with evidence that establishes probable cause that a person has engaged in driving without a license can issue a warrant for that person's arrest. Doing so is in no way prohibited by the US Federal Constitution, nor by any state constitution.